# How can I map already linked images to other images?

Tags: html

The code below is for an image map of one image to have multiple hotspots that are linked to 1 image per hotspot. This works fine. I am stuck trying to figure out how to map those linked images to have their own hotspots as well? This is all contained in a single directory on a local PC.  It will function all offline as a simple software demo, where you can navigate by clicking through the image hotspots to teach the basic navigations of a program.

In this code the hotspot is clicked, and a corresponding image pops up perfectly, just stuck mapping additional images that are linked to first image. Thank you for you input and assistance.

```html
<img usemap="#mymap" src="IV 1.10 System Setting Screen.png" width="1920px">
<map name="#mymap">
    <area alt="IV 1.10 System Menu" title="System Settings Menu" href="IV 1.10 System Setting Screen    
    Menu Drop Down.png" coords="1520,5,1570,53" shape="rect">
    <area alt="Detector Status" title="Detector Status" href="IV 1.10 System Setting Screen with Detector   
    Quicklink.png" coords="1496,2,1407,60" shape="rect">
    <area alt="Help Menu" title="Help Menu" href="Record Issue & Help_About_K_Console_InfoMenu.png"    
    coords="1575,-2,1662,74" shape="rect">
    <area alt="Worklist" title="Worklist" href="IV 1.10 Worklist screen.png" coords="929,3,1030,53"  
    shape="rect">
    <area alt="Views Menu" title="Views Menu" href="" coords="1332,3,1402,50" shape="rect">
 </map>
```

I have tried mapping the images that are the links href="" and mapping them in the same manner, with no success. So I believe my code structure may need to be changed to allow for multiple mapped images and cannot locate any examples of how this is done.

Comment: What _verb_ do you mean by "mapping images"?

Comment: Apologies. an image map is the correct vernacular. Clickable defined areas or hotspots on a image that when clicked will take you to another page. In my case I  have one image that has 48 clickable areas set up and linked to a corresponding page or rather an image. I am needing to make these other images also have clickable areas as well, like the first image and directed to other images.